# Hitting urls using threads

Tags: java, multithreading, url

I am using threads to hit the urls in an arrayList. Need to store the not working urls in another arraylist. However the list of not-working urls changes everytime. Getting a malformed url exception. This exception occurs even for working urls (When tried hitting them manually).

```
public class ThreadTest {

static int i = 0;
static ArrayList<String> arrayOfNotWorking = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<String> arrayOfUrl = new ArrayList<>();

    ThreadTest threadTest = new ThreadTest();
    arrayOfUrl.add("https://www.parkbus.ca");
    arrayOfUrl.add("https://affectingchange.com/projects/fogo-island-");
    arrayOfUrl.add("https://skoll.socialedge.org/?293@@.1ad86d9e");
    arrayOfUrl.add("https://skollsocialedge.org?293@@.1ad86");
    arrayOfUrl.add("https://www.jitabangladesh.com");
    arrayOfUrl.add("https://www.ngobiz.org/picture/File/Social Enterpeuneur-The Case of Definition.pdf");
    arrayOfUrl.add("https://www.mealshare.ca/en/home/");
    arrayOfUrl.add("https://www.oecd.org/cfe/leed/38870491.pdf");
    arrayOfUrl.add("https://doi.org/10.1787/tour-2016-en");
    arrayOfUrl.add("https://www.youtube.com/user/PlaneterraCares");

    try {
        ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(arrayOfUrl.size());
        for (i = 0; i < arrayOfUrl.size(); i++) {
            threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    threadTest.hitUrl(arrayOfUrl.get(i));
                }
            });
        }
        threadPool.shutdown();
        threadPool.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        for (String string : arrayOfNotWorking) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

public static void hitUrl(String actualUrl) {
    try {
        URL obj = new URL(actualUrl);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode > 199 && responseCode < 400) {
        } 
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        arrayOfNotWorking.add(actualUrl);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So what exactly you want here in case of exception? Maintain a list of non-working URL's?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: You are not closing connections - use a try-with-resources statement to avoid leaking resources. This may cause exceptions to be thrown (by going over the max). Also, arrayOfNotWorking is added to from within multiple threads. Protect it with synchronized blocks, or use a thread-safe container instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `notWorkingUrl` within the `hitUrl` method, so each time the method is called the variable gets initialised.

You should define a list of type String in the class, and add the not working URLs to that.

Comment: Have added a list of not working urls "arrayOfNotWorking". This list keeps changing everytime.

Comment: @Qwerky, When I run this piece of code, I get value of `arrayOfNotWorking` different everytime. I think that is her query.

Answer (score 0):

java.net.malformedurlexception is thrown if invalid protocol is used or the url string could not be parsed due to in valid encoding.

Try to identify common problem with such invalid url's and then you can use URLEncoder or String class methods to format such url's